# removing key,value pairs from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

If I have aDict defined like this

```
{'1': 6, '2': 15, '3': 16, '4': 71, '5': 33}
```

and I have a aValue

```
16
```

How do I remove all key/value pairs that contain a value `< aValue`?

I've tried `pop` unsuccessfully. I could probably get away with just changing the value to `0`, but even doing that gives me `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

What I'd really like, is output like this

```
{'3': 16, '4': 71, '5': 33}
```

Slicing and dictionary comprehension are a bit above my head right now, my current non-working code is:

```
for k, v in aDict.iteritems():
    if v < aValue:
        del aDict[k]
```

Comment: use `aDict = {k: v for k, v in aDict.iteritems() if v >= aValue}`

Comment: If you are really against dict comprehension `for k, v in list(aDict.iteritems()):` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think it is better to construct a *new* dictionary, since this is more "declarative", and less error prone: there can be objects that refer to the dictionary and now all of a sudden that dictionary will change.

So you can make a dictionary like:

```
aDict = { k: v for k, v in aDict.iteritems() if v >= aValue }
```

this yields:

```
>>> { k: v for k, v in aDict.iteritems() if v >= aValue }
{'3': 16, '5': 33, '4': 71}
```

we thus assign the *new* dictionary to the same variable, but other attributes, variables, etc. that might link to the old dictionary will not "see" any change.

If you really want to delete the items in the dictionary, you better do *not* iterate and change the dictionary concurrently, you can first construct a list of keys that should be removed, like:

```
ks = [k for k in aDict.iteritems() if v < aValue]
for k in ks:
    del aDict[k]
```

or in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), we can use `.items()` since this is a `list`:

```
# do *not* use this in Python-3.x
for k in aDict.items():
    if v < aValue:
        del aDict[k]
```